# Can two different users with different roles sign up using the same email address

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Can two different types of users (driver and passenger) sign up using the same email address as I want user can login as driver or passenger or they can be both using the same email address.

i have tried to attempt but failed message occur saying the email has been associated by other user

Comment: Seems to me that you want 1 user with 2 roles, **not** 2 users with 1 of the roles each.

Comment: yes that's what i am trying to say

Answer (score 0):

Nope, emails are meant to be primary key, hence they cannot be associated with multiple account.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends with you database structure. If you use the same table for all users and email as unique, they cant. If you use different tables for each user type, they can.
You can change the email to be not unique or use different tables. A great solution would be to allow multiple profiles under parent profile. User logs in with an email, then creates a profile(driver/passenger), the same way you can create several profiles of facebook from your parent account.

Answer (score 0):

Users and roles may be better stored in separate tables。Otherwise, there may be many similar problems with use-related attributes later on。

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase Authentication, each email address can only be associated with one user account even if they have different roles. This is happening because Firebase uses the email address as a unique identifier for the users.

If you want to have two different users with different roles sign up using the same email address, then you should consider implementing Firebase Authentication with providers. In this way, you'll be able to have, for example, a [Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) account and a [Facebook](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login) account that share the same email address. To achieve this, open the Firebase console, and under the Authentication section's Settings tab, you'll find an option called "Create multiple accounts for each identity provider.